# What's the best way to expose EJB calls between JBOSS EAR application and Tomcat WAR application using open-telemetry?

Tags: tomcat, jboss, ejb, open-telemetry

I have multiple JBOSS EAR application deployed in JBOSS and multiple Tomcat WAR application deployed in Tomcat.

Is there a way to instrument remote EJB calls from tomcat application all the way to Jboss EAR application.

I tried using the javaagent instrumentations, but it does not expose the EJB calls. Then I tried to write interceptors (filters) in both tomcat (CLIENT) and JBOSS (SERVER) using custom span. However it still does not expose much details. And I am not sure if this is the only way.

Comment: ya, OpenTelemetry Java agent doesn't have any EJB instrumentation. with custom spans though you should be able to capture whatever details you want (e.g. using span attributes)